# Regex returning null while searching for a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am wroking on a ASP.NET console application using C# that is trying to read some files from a website by logging in and then writing the files on local drive.

I have following Regex which searches for some string in a text file -

```
var fileNames = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+(_+[0-9]+)?\.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)")
                        select new { m.Value }).ToList();
```

This code was working perfectly with my web application doing the same task. But when I m using it in my console application, the `filenames.count` is 0.

What possibly could be the problem while this code still works with my web application?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like you have an extra space after dot and before extension: `\.+ (acc...`.

Comment: Oh that was a mistake while writing the question. corrected

Comment: You should probably post some examples - what value do you expect to match. Also check if your `pageSource` is initialized correctly and has the same value as it does in web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fileNames = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+(_+[0-9]+)?\.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)")                         select m.Value).ToList();
```

That worked for me...

I removed

> select  <strike>new {</strike> m.Value  <strike>}</strike>).ToList();

Thanks for replying and helping guys :)

Comment: In other words, you removed the braces from `{ m.Value }`.  You should mention that in your answer; it took me quite a while to spot the difference.